# Named Argument not found

Tags: excel, vba, methods, arguments

In the following "overwrite" is incorrect. I would like to leave in "source" and "Destination" but it seems the only way forward is to drop all names as in second script?

```
Const initialFileDump As String = "C:\"

Dim FSO As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FSO.CopyFile _
    Source:=initialFileDump & "\" & "test.xlsx", _
    Destination:=initialFileDump & "\" & "testnew.xlsx", _
    overwrite:=True
```

Script2

```
Const initialFileDump As String = "C:\"

Dim FSO As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FSO.CopyFile _
    initialFileDump & "\" & "test.xlsx", _
    initialFileDump & "\" & "testnew.xlsx", _
    True
```

Is there a way to leave in the first two names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `OverWriteFiles` rather than `Overwrite`. It's always worth adding the references to `Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime` so you get the intelli-sense with parameters expected.

[image]

Comment: lol!!! ....thanks msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w(v=vs.84).aspx. You're right about using early binding for dev and then switching to late binding once in production, I just get lazy and go straight to late.

Comment: @whytheq no worries. I think you were looking at a wrong msdn.

Comment: @whytheq check out conditional compilation